# How can I solve the Caution request is not finished yet error?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-core, file-upload

[image]

I'm getting this error while uploading a file, how can I solve this error?
It waits like this for 1 minutes, then the upload process takes place in the remaining 5 seconds, how can I solve this?
[image]

```
function CloudItemUpload(folderId, uploadFileCollectionList, i, directoryPath, files,overWrite) {
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("folderId", folderId);
    formData.append("dType", uploadFileCollectionList[i].dType);
    formData.append("relativePath", uploadFileCollectionList[i].itemRelativePath);
    formData.append("directoryPath", directoryPath);
    formData.append("itemId", uploadFileCollectionList[i].itemId);
    var newItemId = uploadFileCollectionList[i].itemId;
    formData.append("overwrite", overWrite);
    //formData.append("size", size);
    formData.append("fileName", uploadFileCollectionList[i].itemName);
    formData.append('file', files[i]);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Upload/Upload",
        enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        async: true,
        beforeSend: function(request) {
            request.setRequestHeader("serviceUrl", getToLocalStorage("serviceUrl"));
            request.setRequestHeader("token", getToLocalStorage("token"));
            connection.on("lastprogress", function (itemId, progresbar) {
                
                $(".progress-bar").each(function (index, element) {
                    var fileid = $(this).data("fileid");
                    if (fileid === itemId) {
                        $(this).width(progresbar + "%");
                    }
                });
             //   var progressBarValue = $(".progress-custom").find("[data-fileid='" + uploadFileCollectionList[i].itemId + "']").val();
                
             //   $('.progress-bar').eq(count - 1).width(progresbar + "%");
                //if (progresbar == 100) {
                //    connection.on("uploadcontrol", function (isboolean, itemId) {
                //        if (isboolean) {
                //            $('.remove-from-list').each(function (index, element) {

                //                if ($(this).data("fileid") === itemId) {
                //                    $(this).removeClass("red").removeClass("stop").addClass("green").addClass("check");
                //                }
                //            });
 
 
                //        }

                //    });
                //}
            }
            );
            try {
                connection.start().catch(err => console.error(err.toString())).then(response => console.log("connected"));//unutma
            } catch (e) {

            }
             
        },
        headers: { 'serviceUrl': getToLocalStorage("serviceUrl"), 'token': getToLocalStorage("token") },
        data: formData,
        success: function () {
            UploadControl(newItemId, overWrite);

            
        }
    });
}
```

the code part is completed like this.
I still don't understand why you waited so long

Comment: Do you run this project in loaclhost or the server? What's the size of the file you upload.

Comment: I am running on localhost. 5mb in size